# Finding the differential equation solved by the function in the picture

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a question on Strang's Differential equations and linear algebra. It asks which differential equation is solved by the function in the image:
[image]

I guessed the differential equation:
$$y'=y+1-2e^{2-t}H(t-1)$$
With y(0)=0.

Which I obtained by rewriting the function as:
$$y_2=e^t-1+(e^{2-t}-e^t)H(t-1)$$
My question is if this is a valid answer. My procedure to verify this was:

In the case $t<1$, thi equation becomes:
$$y'=y+1$$
With solution:
$$y=e^t-1$$

When $t\geq 1$ we have:
$$y'=y+1-2e^{2-t}H(t-1)$$
$$y'-y=1-2e^{2-t}H(t-1)$$
$$(e^{-t}y)'=e^{-t}-2e^{2-2t}H(t-1)$$
$$y=e^t\int_0^te^{-u}du-\int_0^t2e^{2-2u}H(u-1)du$$
$$y=e^t(1-e^{-t})-e^t\int_1^t2e^{2-2u}du$$
$$y=e^t-1-e^t(1-e^{2-2t})=e^{2-t}-1$$

I'm unsure of my procedure, as it is quite informal and there is really no good explanation as to what is really happening when I derive the heavyside function in the book, other than a quite unsatisfactory discussion of the delta function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right

Taking Laplace transform of your DE we get
$$s Y-\frac{1}{s}+\frac{2 e^{1-s}}{s+1}-Y=0$$
$$Y=\frac{-2 e^{1-s} s+s+1}{s^3-s}$$
And applying the inverse transform
$$y=\left(e^{2-t}-e^t\right) H (t-1)+e^t-1$$

I plotted the function and got a graph that is the one you started from

[image]